# Are there any mini pumps that can be mounted on a wide rectangular frame?

Tags: mountain-bike, tools, pump

On my previous MTB (a hard tail from 2002), I had mounted a mini pump (not sure which brand) under/next to the bottle cage. The pump came with a frame mount and a velcro strip to secure it in place in the frame.

When I tried to mount this pump on my new bike (2018 Trek Fuel EX 8), I found that the frame mount of the pump does not fit the frame of the Trek - it's made for a round down tube, while the Trek's down tube (where its only bottle cage can be mounted) is more like a wide rectangle. The pump's frame mount doesn't fit that since the rounded shape does not fit on the bike's frame shape.

Having looked at other mini pumps that come with a frame mount, I've noticed (from photos) that most of the frame mounts seem to be similar to what I have - expecting a rounded down tube.

Are there any mini pumps that can be mounted on a frame like the Trek's? I've checked my son's Focus and my wife's Liv bike, and the pump does not fit on their frames either.

If not, is there any other clever way to mount the mini pump on the bike? I don't think I can use the seat post, since it is a drop post...

[image: https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0260/2045/products/tref_fuel_ex_8_large.jpg?v=1510011203]

Comment: One issue with these flattop+wide tube MB frames is the pump has to sit a long way out and is far more exposed to getting knocked.  I gave up and decided to go to CO in a seat bag for short rides and carry the pump in my backpack for longer back country rides.

Comment: I have added a stock photo of this bike model.  If its wrong please use revert and add your own photo.

Comment: Yes, that‘s the model that I have. Mine‘s in black, and has the Shimano XT instead of the SRAM gear, but otherwise the same. Thanks for adding the photo!

Comment: The handyman's secret weapon:  Duct tape!!

Answer (score 5):

There are mini pump holders that attach directly to bottle cage mount points under the cage, and hold the pump to one side of the bottle. I have one that has long slots for the cage bolts that allow the holder to be mounted further away from the centerline of the frame and accommodate wide tubes.

You can also try mounting your pump holder on the seat tube or top tube.

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I'm looking for. From looking at product photos, I have not seen any that have these long slots... Care to share which one you have?

Comment: It's a old one that I'm not even sure which country I acquired it in.

Comment: Thanks for the response anyway - appreciate it! I'm also thinking about potentially fixing the pump to the bottom of my mini saddle bag...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a "mini floor pump" which can be strapped on pretty-much anywhere on the bike that is out of your way.

[image: https://criggie.org.nz/pictures/bikes/m5/20180520_5-chainrings-and-boom.jpg Own work]

(Please disregard the battery under the velcro and temporary wiring wrap.)

That holder is designed to sit on top of two bottle mounts, rather than off to the side.  So its a thin flattish mount on the back rather than being designed to sit off to the side.  [Better photos on the reseller's site.](http://www.wiggle.co.nz/lifeline-motion-floor-mount-mini-pump-black-one-size/)

There are no rivnuts on that bike so I used the two provided cable ties.  They seem fine so far.

Comment: That looks interesting, thanks! I'm using my bike's single bottle mount for a bottle cage, but could use the cable ties to mount the pump under the top tube. I've also found the Zefal Doodad pump mounts, which use velcro straps plus a moulded piece of rubber to secure the pump pretty much anywhere on the bike - maybe I'll give that a try...

Answer (score 2):

If you're okay to buy a new pump, what about a frame pump?  As pictured, they wedge into a corner of your frame and run parallel to the top or seat post.

[image: https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0309/9521/products/impero_full_2000x.jpg?v=1526483140]

Downside, they're not very popular for aesthetic reasons, and your full-suspension bike has fewer places it could go.  Perhaps under the top tube?

Comment: Not sure whether there are any frame pumps that fit the geometry of a fully...

Answer (score 1):

Would fixing the pump mount with a couple of hose clamps be a solution for you?

And by hose clamps I mean those devices:

[image] [image]

Remember to use some electrical insulation tape to protect the paint on your frame and measure the perimeter of your frame to pick the correct size of the hose clamp.

If the clamps shown above won't please your aesthetics, there are other models, like those:
[image]

Comment: That might work, but is somewhat ugly. I'd prefer an off-the-shelf solution if possible...

Comment: Heavy duty zip ties would be a better solution.

Comment: +1 for this - its harder to steal off the bike than plastic slipties.